# Show username of logged in user in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have login and logout system in **ZF2**. I want to show username of logged in user when he/she is logged in. Screen shot is given below:
[image]

I have different views like view/provinces/index.phtml, view/districts/index.phtml, etc.

I have layout.phtml in view/layout/layout.phtml, in which I described layout for admin which is for every view. So It is necessary to access **username of logged in user** in layout.phtml.

I have also corresponding controllers like Controller/ProvincesController.php, Controller/DistrictsController.php etc. I can access **username** of **logged in** user in Controller/ProvincesController.php etc by the code:

```
public function getAuthService()
{
    $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService'); 
    return $this->authservice;  
}

$username = $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->read();
```

But I am unable to access value of **username of logged in user** in layout.phtml.

So if anyone know about it or have simple idea or practice about it, then let me know please.

Module.php:

```
<?php 

namespace Admin;

use Admin\Model\Profile;
use Admin\Model\ProfileTable;

use Admin\Model\Provinces;
use Admin\Model\ProvincesTable;

use Admin\Model\Districts;
use Admin\Model\DistrictsTable; 

use Admin\Model\User;
use Admin\Model\UserTable;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface; 

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
//class Module
{

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(),
        'aliases' => array(),

        'factories' => array( 

        // SERVICES
          'AuthService' => function($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'user','username','password', 'MD5(?)');

            $authService = new AuthenticationService();
            $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
            return $authService;
          },    

          // DB
          'UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
            $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
            $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
            return $table;
          },
          'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
            return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null,   
            $resultSetPrototype);
          },

          // FORMS
          'LoginForm' => function ($sm) {
            $form = new \Admin\Form\LoginForm();
            $form->setInputFilter($sm->get('LoginFilter'));
            return $form;
          },


           // FILTERS
          'LoginFilter' => function ($sm) {
            return new \Admin\Form\LoginFilter();
           },


            'Admin\Model\ProvincesTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProvincesTableGateway');
                $table = new ProvincesTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'ProvincesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Provinces());
                return new TableGateway('provinces', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },

            'Admin\Model\DistrictsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('DistrictsTableGateway');
                $table = new DistrictsTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'DistrictsTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Districts());
                return new TableGateway('districts', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },



        ),

        'invokables' => array(),
        'services' => array(),
        'shared' => array(),

    );
} 

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array( 
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
        // if we're in a namespace deeper than one level we need to fix the \ in the path
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What module do you use for authentication? Your Own? Or external module?

Comment: I have my own module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommend way would be to use `identity` (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.identity.html) view helper. Then in any view model you could use it as follow:

```
if ($user = $this->identity()) {
     echo 'Logged in as ' . $this->escapeHtml($user->getUsername());
 } else {
     echo 'Not logged in';
 }
```

In order to make it work you have to register your authentication service under specific name- `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`.

So in your `module.config.php` file, add to `service_manager`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'AuthService', // <--- this line
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'AuthService' => 'Your\Authentication\Class',
    ),
),
```

Then you should be able to use `identity` controller plugin and view helper.

In your case, `Module.php` should look like this:

```
...
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(),
        'aliases' => array(
             'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'AuthService', // <--- this line
         ),

        'factories' => array( 

        // SERVICES
          'AuthService' => function($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'user','username','password', 'MD5(?)');

            $authService = new AuthenticationService();
            $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
            return $authService;
          },    

          // DB
          'UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
            $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
            $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
            return $table;
          },
          'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
            return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null,   
            $resultSetPrototype);
          },

          // FORMS
          'LoginForm' => function ($sm) {
            $form = new \Admin\Form\LoginForm();
            $form->setInputFilter($sm->get('LoginFilter'));
            return $form;
          },


           // FILTERS
          'LoginFilter' => function ($sm) {
            return new \Admin\Form\LoginFilter();
           },


            'Admin\Model\ProvincesTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProvincesTableGateway');
                $table = new ProvincesTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'ProvincesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Provinces());
                return new TableGateway('provinces', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },

            'Admin\Model\DistrictsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('DistrictsTableGateway');
                $table = new DistrictsTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'DistrictsTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Districts());
                return new TableGateway('districts', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },



        ),

        'invokables' => array(),
        'services' => array(),
        'shared' => array(),

    );
} 
...
```

Then in your layout or any other .phtml file:

```
layout.phtml
...
<?php if ($this->identity()): ?>
<p>Welcome, <?php echo $this->identity()->getUsername(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear brother, you helped to solve my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Taking help of Mr. SzymonM's answer, I changed my Module.php as suggested by him, and write the following simple code in layout.phtml

This solve my issue and username is shown with first letter in Upper case.

```
<?php 
    if ($this->identity())
    {  
        echo ucfirst($this->identity());    
    } 
?>  
//ucfirst is php function which make first letter Uppercase.
```